# Page configuration <link> using external href

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0, page-layouts

In my `/app/design/frontend/<vendor>/<theme>/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml` file I am trying to reference our CDN for things like our author link.  This is what I have now.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" src="https://repo.wsu.edu/spine/1/favicon.ico" />
        <link type="text/plain" rel="author" src="https://repo.wsu.edu/spine/1/authors.txt" />
        <link type="text/html" rel="help" src="https://brand.wsu.edu" />

    </head>
    <body>
        <move element="catalog.topnav" destination="spine.spine.glue" before="-"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

what I get out is this

```
<link  rel="shortcut icon" href="http://mage2.wsu.dev/static/frontend/wsu/wsu_base/en_US/https://repo.wsu.edu/spine/1/favicon.ico" />
<link  rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="http://mage2.wsu.dev/static/frontend/wsu/wsu_base/en_US/Magento_Theme/favicon.ico" />
<link  rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="http://mage2.wsu.dev/static/frontend/wsu/wsu_base/en_US/Magento_Theme/favicon.ico" />
<link  type="text/plain" rel="author" href="http://mage2.wsu.dev/static/frontend/wsu/wsu_base/en_US/https://repo.wsu.edu/spine/1/authors.txt" />
<link  type="text/html" rel="help" href="http://mage2.wsu.dev/static/frontend/wsu/wsu_base/en_US/https://brand.wsu.edu" />
```

The issues are first, the icon didn't get replaced, would have expected it to for items that only really work with one of them declared like the `shortcut icon`.  This is a short fall in my eyes but I get that I more then likely will need to do some remove/delete/unset type of node in the xml to rid the layout of the system driven link that needs to come from our CDN.

What I am not finding any information on in the documentation is why we are getting

`http://mage2.wsu.dev/static/frontend/wsu/wsu_base/en_US/https://repo.wsu.edu/spine/1/authors.txt`

when we expected

`https://repo.wsu.edu/spine/1/authors.txt`

from the node

`<link type="text/plain" rel="author" src="https://repo.wsu.edu/spine/1/authors.txt" />`.

Is there a way to use the external url with out an override of the core?  If not, any ideas on the best point to inject the change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out `src_type="url"` is what you need to add.  Althought it was not apparent in the `urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd` the `src_type` attribute seems to carry anywhere the `src` attribute is used as well. Doing

`<link type="text/plain" rel="author" src="https://repo.wsu.edu/spine/1/authors.txt" src_type="url" />`

produces the expected

`<link type="text/plain" rel="author" href="https://repo.wsu.edu/spine/1/authors.txt"/>`